# Flexdatalist data: is not picking data from database

Tags: jquery, flexdatalist

I am new to flexdatalist but bear with me. As I try to set data in flexdatalist data: I got nothing can be a common problem with me but as there's no enough material for such problem on internet i will like to ask experts how to solve my problem.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "Handler1.ashx?action=" + "getdataflex",
            success: function (data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(res)
           
            $("#flexdata").flexdatalist({
                data: res,
            });
        }
    })
data:res doesn't pick data,
```

data is in the form of:

```
0
: 
(5) ['110', 'customer', 'khalid', 'asd', 'GHFD']
1
: 
(5) ['111', 'customer', 'khalid', 'asd', '0']
length:2
  [[Prototype]]
     :Array(0)
```

I also tried to send only one column but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue resolved as flexdatalist only accepts data in key:value pair but I was trying to put an array there so data wasn't going to flexdatalist as planed.